# Cannot Set Default Term Value on Column

Tags: managed-metadata, column

I have a Meta Term Column in a Document Library that want to default to a value in my Meta Term Store.  However, the SharePoint UI does not ever enable the "Save" button when for my selected tag.  Why is it preventing me from setting it?  Is it possible?

Comment: is this still an issue? Can you send a screen shot of what you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks but it appears this must be set using the "Library Settings" | "Column Default Value Settings" Setting default value settings there for your Meta Terms works fine.